# For loop is printing every other line and I need it to print every line

Tags: loops, dictionary

I am trying to iterate through a file, spilt each item into a list, then put the the 2 items into a dictionary ( ex: {binary : char } ) but the loop starts on the second line and continues to skip every other. How come?

def create_dictionary(file_name):

```
file_in = open("ascii-codes.csv" , "r")
adic = {}

for item in file_in:
    values = file_in.readline().split(",")
    binary = values[0]
    char = values[1]
    adic[binary] = char 

print(adic)
```

Answer (score 0):

`for item in file_in:` already iterates over the lines of the file, so if you do `values = file_in.readline()` inside that iteration, you only get every second line into `values`.

`for item in file_in` already gives you `item` as one line in your file to work with inside the loop, no need to do `readline()`.

```
for item in file_in:
    values = item.split(",")
    ...
```